# Ease-of-use & accessibility enhancement for user with tremor

Tags: screen, accessibility

I gave my good friend a Lumia 925 for his birthday about a month ago.  He has a mild but noticeable tremor, especially when performing fine motor tasks.  He has been doing okay learning how to use his first smartphone.  But the difficulty he has in controlling the UI is getting in the way of really mastering the device.

Are there any ease of access features or add-on packages that would help him?

One thought I have is that if screen touch sensitivity can be reduced, it would prevent situations where the phone detects a fingertip touch, even though he was really hesitating and not trying to touch the screen.

Another idea is to configure the detection thresholds for (1) speed of swipes and (2) duration of touch-and-hold gestures.

I wonder if Windows Phone OS even allows a third party developer to interact with the screen input vectors like this.  The developer's code would be inserted between the screen input events and any running application.  That sounds like a security risk that a secure system like WP simply would not allow.

Comment: I tried to add the tags 'ease-of-use' and 'accessibility' to this question, but they don't exist and I don't have enough reputation to create them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such a thing as of now. You still can do few things to make things easier for him.:

- Change font size to a larger size. This will make some objects much bigger, making it easier for him to tap even with the tremors.
- If the phone has update 3 (black), there is a new accessibility option. It is meant for the visually impaired but it can help your friend. It will make the tiles and buttons bigger, again making things easier to tap with tremors, less chances of taping other unwanted buttons.

AFAIK, developers can only get information about the current accessibility options from the WP setting, and change the behavior/look of their apps accordingly.